# Connecting NodeJS to MySQL without a module

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm aware of the popularity of a module like [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) for connecting to a database from an application, but I can't find any info on the connecting process without using a module like this.

Obviously I could go fishing around the modules themselves for the answer, but is there really no user-case for simple connections with simple queries without module dependency and bloated functionality?

I find it strange given the very simple I/O of a process like MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has less to do with node.js and more to do with knowing how to implement the [MySql client/server protocol](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html).  You simply need to create a [tcp connection](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectionlistener) to the server and send the correct format and sequence of data per the protocol.  node-mysql has done the difficult part: abstracting the protocol into something much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is subjective, but looking at the example in https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
for me looks like simple connection and simple Query

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

If you have a look to the source code you'll see what it takes to implement the mysql client protocol, I would say that is not that simple
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/Connection.js
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/tree/master/lib/protocol

But again this is something subjective,IMHO I don't think that there is a simpler way to query MySql.